# Port not reachable although it is in a listening state

Tags: networking, vagrant, port

I am using `vagrant` to deploy several `redis` nodes.

However:

On one hand

```
(master)*$ vagrant ssh redis.node.1
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-143-generic x86_64)

New release '18.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
Last login: Mon Mar 18 15:03:21 2019 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@redis:~$ ss -tulapn | grep -i 6379
tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:6379                  *:*                  
tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:16379                 *:*                  
tcp    LISTEN     0      128      :::6379                 :::*                  
tcp    LISTEN     0      128      :::16379                :::*
```

But from my host machine:

```
(master)*$ ping -c 1 redis.node.1
PING redis.node.1 (192.168.54.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from redis.node.1 (192.168.54.11): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.235 ms

--- redis.node.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.235/0.235/0.235/0.000 ms
(master)*$ nc -zv -w 2 redis.node.1 6379
nc: connect to redis.node.1 port 6379 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to redis.node.1 port 6379 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

How is this possible?

How can I further troubleshoot this?

I have disabled and stopped `ufw` on `redis.node.1`, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely had to do with `vagrant` and `virtualbox` provider as also their virtual interface handling;

Doing an `ip route` showed the following entry

```
192.168.54.0/24 dev vboxnet6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.54.1
```

**even** after running `vagrant destroy`

The above `cidr` corresponds to the network I am creating in `Vagrantfile`

The specific virtual interface should have been deleted after destroying the `vagrant` environment, however it didn't, creating some kind of networking limbo and therefor misrouting of packets (?)

Chaning the private network's IP address range or explicitly deleting the above vface solved the issue.